# ABAP Webdynpro error in supply function for a singleton

Tags: abap, webdynpro

```
The following error text was processed in system EH5 : Invalid operand type for the MOVE-CORRESPONDING statement.
◾ The error occurred on the application server CRMEHP2_EH5_24 and in the work process 8 . 
◾ The termination type was: RABAX_STATE
◾ The ABAP call stack was: 
Method: IF_WD_CONTEXT_ELEMENT~GET_STATIC_ATTRIBUTES of program CL_WDR_CONTEXT_ELEMENT========CP
Method: BOOKINGS_READ of program /1BCWDY/0AA4D2ZOSMXD1LD8M8M2==CP
Method: BOOKINGS_READ of program /1BCWDY/0AA4D2ZOSMXD1LD8M8M2==CP
Method: SUPPLY_ELEMENTS of program CL_WDR_CONTEXT_NODE_VAL=======CP
Method: IF_WD_CONTEXT_NODE~GET_LEAD_SELECTION of program CL_WDR_CONTEXT_NODE_VAL=======CP
Method: IF_WD_CONTEXT_NODE~GET_LEAD_SELECTION of program CL_WDR_CONTEXT_NODE_MAP=======CP
Method: GET_LEAD_SELECTION of program CL_WDR_TABLE_DATA_PROVIDER====CP
Method: UPDATE_RANGE_SELECT_START of program CL_WDR_TABLE_DATA_PROVIDER====CP
Method: GET_TABLE_DATA of program CL_WDR_TABLE_DATA_PROVIDER====CP
Method: GET_VISIBLE_TABLE_DATA of program CL_WDR_TABLE_DATA_PROVIDER====CP
```

I have created two controllers

Componentcontroller is bound to flightinfo table. This table is populated. However, if_componentcontroller=>element_flightinfo dosen't fetch any data. Why?

Customcontroller2 is bound to bookingtab table.

```
Method:
**METHOD bookings_read.**
  DATA:
    stru_flight             TYPE if_componentcontroller=>element_flightinfo,
    itab_booking            TYPE if_customcontroller2=>elements_bookingtab.

* Get Parent Element.
* Error is here: All attributes of stru_flight are either blank or zero.
* The error disappears once CALL METHOD is commented.
  CALL METHOD parent_element->get_static_attributes
    IMPORTING
      static_attributes = stru_flight.

* read bookings
*Rest of the satatements work fine.
  SELECT * FROM sbook
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE itab_booking
    WHERE carrid = stru_flight-carrid
      AND connid = stru_flight-connid
      AND fldate = stru_flight-fldate.

* bind all the elements
  node->bind_table(
    new_items =  itab_booking
    set_initial_elements = abap_true ).

**ENDMETHOD.**
```

Definition of parent_element, and stru_flights structure

```
NODE    Importing   IF_WD_CONTEXT_NODE      
PARENT_ELEMENT  Importing   IF_WD_CONTEXT_ELEMENT       
stru_flight             TYPE if_componentcontroller=>element_flightinfo,

  **CALL METHOD parent_element->get_static_attributes
    IMPORTING
      static_attributes = stru_flight.**
```

- implicit constant definition for context node bookingtab types:

  Element_bookingtab type SBOOK,
  Elements_bookingtab type standard table of Element_bookingtab with default key.

Comment: What is the type declaration of `if_customcontroller2=>elements_bookingtab`?

Comment: And how is the "parent element" context node declared? Please provide more relevant info if you want people to help you.